# awk script to provides a structured listing

Tags: awk

I'm trying to create awk script that can provide a structured listing of account information for all UIDs greater than 1000.
This is what I tried:
[This is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcRus.png)

```
BEGIN { FS=":"}

$3>1000 && $3<2000 {print $1   "  uid: " $3 " Full name: " $5 " Home dir "$6 " Shel :"$7}BEGIN { FS=":"}
```

[the resualt i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmefg.png)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: BEGIN { FS=":"}

$3>1000 && $3<2000 {print $1   "  uid: " $3 " Full name: " $5 " Home dir "$6 " Shel :"$7}BEGIN { FS=":"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN { FS=":" }
{
  if($3 > 1000 && $3 < 2000){
    print $1
    print " uid: " $3
    print " Full name: " $5
    print " Home dir: " $6
    print " Shel: " $7
  }
}
```

First line - `BEGIN { FS=":" }` - sets field separator to `:` on the beginning of script run. Every line will be splitted to separate columns and saved to variables `$1` - `$n` (`n` is number of separated fields).

After that you have there `{   }` and this will be executed for every input line. There is the `if` inside and it checks `uid` value, `print`s will print required datas if value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that awk is interpreting the UIDs as strings; you can force it to interpret as integers for the comparison by doing integer calculations with it.

The easiest way is to add a 0 to the value.

So

```
$3 + 0 > 1000 && $3 + 0 < 2000
```

Here is a good awk reference for this: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers